# C# Drawing scaled Images JPG, PNG using DrawImage does not look correct

Tags: c#, scaling, drawimage

I am trying to Draw an Image (JPG, TIFF, PNG) on the background of my user control. My user control will highlight certain portions of the Image using Rectangles. If I draw the image unscaled they are looking correct. But when I draw then Scaled [Fit to Page] then the image is not looking correct. For PNG some times it fails to load the image even.

The application is not a image processing app but I still want to show the Image scaled and can see the image properly.

Thanks
--HAN

Comment: Could you post some sample code please? You may try to use the code here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa327544(v=VS.71).aspx

Comment: This question needs a code snippet, a link to a screenshot showing the bad image and the exception message + stack trace when the image doesn't load.  Hurry up, your question is on the front page for less than 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Before Drawing int he paint event I have added the following

```
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
```

Then the images looked alright.

Thanks for your comments.

--Hari